# Алгоритм Флойда-Уоршалла на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Не могу восстановить путь, т к список Parent остается заполнен None после всех итераций. Как это исправить?
Список списков F заполняется верно. Нужна помощь именно для случая, когда F[k][i][j] имеет именно 3 индекса

```
W = [[0, 2, math.inf, 3, 1, math.inf, math.inf, 10],
     [2, 0, 4, math.inf, math.inf, math.inf, math.inf, math.inf],
     [math.inf, 4, 0, math.inf, math.inf, math.inf, math.inf, 3],
     [3, math.inf, math.inf, 0, math.inf, math.inf, math.inf, 8],
     [1, math.inf, math.inf, math.inf, 0, 2, math.inf, math.inf],
     [math.inf, math.inf, math.inf, math.inf, 2, 0, 3, math.inf],
     [math.inf, math.inf, math.inf, math.inf, math.inf, 3, 0, 1],
     [10, math.inf, 3, 8, math.inf, math.inf, 1, 0],
     ]

N = len(W)

F = [[[None for j in range(N)] for i in range(N)] for k in range(N + 1)]
Parent = [[None for j in range(N)] for i in range(N)]
for k in range(N + 1):
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            if k == 0:
                F[0][i][j] = W[i][j]
            else:
                F[k][i][j] = min(F[k - 1][i][j], F[k - 1][i][k - 1] + F[k - 1][k - 1][j])
                Parent[i][j] = Parent[k - 1][j]
```

Comment: Так откуда в `Parent` возьмётся что-то, если оно само из себя со сдвигом копируется, а там ничего кроме `None` нету? Наверное, какой-то шаг пропущен, на котором в `Parent` что-то ещё попадает.

Comment: не остается пустым, заполнен None

Comment: Судя по википедии там не `None` надо заполнять всё-таки первоначально: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0

Comment: если нужен итоговый результат и цель не разбираться в алгоритме, то реализация как таковая присутствует в `SciPy`, а именно `from scipy.sparse.csgraph import floyd_warshall`